# LINQ to Entities, several one-to-one references to the same tables and naming

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I've started porting a .NET SQL Server application to LINQ to Entities. I have (among others...) one table called Users, and one called Time. Time is reported on a specific user (UserId), but it is also recorded which user made the report (InsertedByUserId) and possibly who has updated the Time since insert (UpdatedByUserId). This gives me three references to the table Users.

When I generate a .EDMX from this I get three references to the table Users: User, User1 and User2. Without manual edit I have no way of knowing which one refers to the UserId, InsertedByUserId or UpdatedByUserId field.

How do others solve this? Maybe it's not necessary to register ALL references, and stick with InsertedByUserId and UpdatedByUserId as ints?

(The manual edit wouldn't be a problem if the database were never updated, but as we make changes to the database every now and then we occasionally have to regenerate the .EMDX, thus removing all manual changes.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe should add that I am using ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jos,

Generally when I make my foreign keys,  I name them accordingly.  From the Entity designer you can differentiate between the different Navigation Properties (ie User, User1, User2) by looking at the FK association (as long as you named your foreign keys distinctly).   For Instance I have a `ModifiedById` and `CreatedById` field in each table.  Both fields reference my `SystemUser` table,   My foreign keys are named like this: `FK_[TableName]_SystemUser_CreatedBy` and `FK_[TableName]_SystemUser_ModifiedBy`.

[image]

You should notice that in the Navigation properties you can see the Foreign key.   You can also modify the name of the Navigation Property (which is in the Conceptual Side "CSDL portion" of the EDMX), and this change will stay when you update your EDMX from the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what I wanted to know, I name my FKs and then manually edit the Navigation Properties, and instead of deleting the EDMX I use the refresh/update function. That's how you do it? I imagined the EDMX generator would be smarter, and that I did something wrong..